# How to create colision detection with 3d objects?

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, collision-detection, gravity

I'm creating a re-make of **atari 8bit** game called [spindizzy](https://youtu.be/G5WbTEbO-Qw) as my school project.

I figured out how to render it using casting `3d points` to `2d perspective point`.

I also can spin shapes *(with minor problem of order of rendering)*.

My goal was something like this:

`Vector3D -> Vector2D` - done

`Block -> [[Vector3D]] -> [[Vector2D]] -> [Shape]` - done

`Map -> [Location] -> [[[Block]]]`

But I have no idea what should chandle colision detection, and how to chandle it.

My target language is `js` but it does not matter if given answer is in other language or just description of how to solve this problem.
Frameworks are not allowed.

I'm using `2d` context of canvas.

[Here](https://github.com/koziejka/spindizzy) you can see my code.

I'll be aslo grateful for the links and suggestions.

Comment: hey I'm new to this kind of development, currently trying to run the source code, I am just getting the warning msg not able to see any output. How can i check game is running ?

Comment: You have to run `npm start` in cmd | terminal (you have to have node instaled) then just open `index.html`

Comment: Okay do i need to manually launch index.html ? when i open that file no game events happening

Comment: It's just drawing now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Surfaces and normals.

Ignoring  the projection and working only in 3D space with some assumptions.

- All blocks are aligned with the x,y axis.
- All blocks have the height of each corner.
- All blocks can have either one flat surface a quad, or be split into two triangles.
- The Split blocks are either split from top left to bottom right or from top right to bottom left.
- Quad (unsplit block) 4 height points must be on the same plane.
- Blocks are always 1 unit width (x axis) and 1 unit in depth (y axis).
- It is possible to have an invalid block. To be a valid block at least 2 points for each face must have the same height. A block with all height set to a different value is not a valid block. (this matches the conditions of the game in the video)

Each block is defined by one object that holds the position (x,y,z), corner heights, the type (split1, split2, or quad) and the surface norm/s

A single function will return the height of a point at x,y on the block. The blocks pNorm property will be set to the surface normal at that point. (Do not modify the normal. If you need to modify it create a copy first)

The surface normal is a line perpendicular to the plane. When you do a height test the property `block.pNorm` is set to the appropriate normal. The normal is used to determine the direction the ball should roll. (I have not included any z movement, the ball is stuck to the surface). The normal is also used to determine shading, and what direction the ball would bounce.

#### A Demo

The best way to explain is via a demo. There is a lot of code to get the demo happening so please do ask if you have any questions.

> **Note** the code is written with a little ES6 so will need babel to run on legacy browsers.

**UPDATE** First post I had a bug I did not spot (normals were incorrectly set). I have fixed it now. I have also added an error that will throw a RangeError if the map contains a invalid block.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);


// block types 
const types = {
    quad : 1,
    split1 : 2, // split from top left to bottom right
    split2 : 3, // split from top right to bottom left
}
/*
// A block object example to define meaning of properties
var blockObject = {
    x : 0, // top left base x pos
    y : 0, // top left base y pos
    z : 0, // top left base z pos
    norm1, // normal of quad or top right or bottom right triangles
    norm2, // normal of quad or top left or bottom left triangles 
    p1 : 0,  // top left
    p2 : 0,  // top right
    p3 : 0,  // bottom right
    p4 : 0,  // bottom left
    type : types.quad,
    pNorm : null, // this is set when a height test is done. It is the normal at the point of the height test
}*/

// compute the surface normal from two vectors on the surface. (cross product of v1,v2)
function getSurfaceNorm(x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2){
    // normalise vectors 
    var d1= Math.hypot(x1,y1,z1);
    x1 /= d1;
    y1 /= d1;
    z1 /= d1;
    var d2= Math.hypot(x2,y2,z2);
    x2 /= d2;
    y2 /= d2;
    z2 /= d2;
    var norm = {}
    norm.x = y1 * z2 - z1 * y2;
    norm.y = z1 * x2 - x1 * z2;
    norm.z = x1 * y2 - y1 * x2;
    return norm;
}
// This defines a block with p1-p2 the height of the corners 
// starting top left and clockwise around to p4 bottom left
// If the block is split with 2 slopes then it will be 
// of type.split1 or type.split2. If a single slope then it is a type.quad
// Also calculates the normals
function createBlock(x,y,z,h1,h2,h3,h4,type){
    var norm1,norm2;
    if(type === types.quad){
        norm1 = norm2 = getSurfaceNorm(1, 0, h2 - h1, 0, 1, h4 - h1);
    }else if(type === types.split1){
        norm1 = getSurfaceNorm(1, 0, h2 - h1, 1, 1, h3 - h1);
        norm2 = getSurfaceNorm(0, 1, h2 - h1, 1, 1, h3 - h1);
    }else{
        norm1 = getSurfaceNorm(0, 1, h2-h3, 1, 0, h4 - h3);
        norm2 = getSurfaceNorm(1, 0, h2 - h1, 0, 1, h4 - h1);
    } 
    return {
        p1 : h1,  // top left
        p2 : h2,  // top right
        p3 : h3,  // bottom right
        p4 : h4,  // bottom left
        x,y,z,type,
        norm1,norm2,
    }
}
        
        
// get the height on the block at x,y
// also sets the surface block.pNorm to match the correct normal
function getHeight(block,x,y){
    var b = block; // alias to make codes easier to read.
    if(b.type === types.quad){
        b.pNorm = b.norm1;
        if(b.p1 === b.p2){
            return (b.p3 - b.p1) * (y % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
        }
        return (b.p2 - b.p1) * (x % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
    }else if(b.type === types.split1){
        if(x % 1 > y % 1){ // on top right side
            b.pNorm = b.norm1;
            if(b.p1 === b.p2){
                if(b.p1 === b.p3){
                    return b.p1 + b.z;
                }
                return (b.p3 - b.p1) * (y % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
            }
            if(b.p2 === b.p3){
                return (b.p2 - b.p1) * (x % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
            }
            return (b.p3 - b.p2) * (y % 1) + (b.p2 - b.p1) * (x % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
        }
        // on bottom left size
        b.pNorm = b.norm2;
        if(b.p3 === b.p4){
            if(b.p1 === b.p3){
                return b.p1 + b.z;
            }
            return (b.p3 - b.p1) * (y % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
        }
        if(b.p1 === b.p4){
            return (b.p3 - b.p1) * (x % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
        }
        var h = (b.p4 - b.p1) * (y % 1);
        var h1 = b.p3 - (b.p4 - b.p1) + h;
        return (h1 - (h + b.p1)) * (x % 1) + (h + b.p1) + b.z;
    }        
    if(1 - (x % 1) < y % 1){ // on bottom right side
        b.pNorm = b.norm1;
        if(b.p3 === b.p4){
            if(b.p3 === b.p2){
                return b.p2 + b.z;
            }
            return (b.p3 - b.p2) * (y % 1) + b.p4 + b.z;
        }
        if(b.p2 === b.p3){
            return (b.p4 - b.p2) * (x % 1) + b.p2 + b.z;
        }
        var h = (b.p3 - b.p2) * (y % 1);
        var h1 = b.p4 - (b.p3 - b.p2) + h;
        return (h + b.p2 - h1) * (x % 1) + h1 + b.z;
    }
    // on top left size
    b.pNorm = b.norm2;    
    if(b.p1 === b.p2){
        if(b.p1 === b.p4){
            return b.p1 + b.z;
        }
        return (b.p4 - b.p1) * (y % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
    }
    if(b.p1 === b.p4){
        return (b.p2 - b.p1) * (x % 1) + b.p1 + b.z;
    }
    var h = (b.p4 - b.p1) * (y % 1);
    var h1 = b.p2 + h;
    return (h1 - (h + b.p1)) * (x % 1) + (h + b.p1) + b.z;

}
const projection = {
    width : 20,
    depth : 20, // y axis
    height : 8, // z axis
    xSlope : 0.5,
    ySlope : 0.5,
    originX : canvas.width / 2,
    originY : canvas.height / 4,
    toScreen(x,y,z,point = [],pos = 0){
        point[pos] = x * this.width - y * this.depth + this.originX;
        point[pos + 1] = x * this.width * this.xSlope + y * this.depth * this.ySlope -z * this.height + this.originY;
        return point;
    }
}
// working arrays to avoid excessive GC hits
var pointArray = [0,0]
var workArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
function drawBlock(block,col,lWidth,edge){
    var b = block;
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.lineWidth = lWidth;
    ctx.beginPath();
    projection.toScreen(b.x,     b.y,     b.z + b.p1, workArray, 0);
    projection.toScreen(b.x + 1, b.y,     b.z + b.p2, workArray, 2);
    projection.toScreen(b.x + 1, b.y + 1, b.z + b.p3, workArray, 4);
    projection.toScreen(b.x,     b.y + 1, b.z + b.p4, workArray, 6);
    if(b.type === types.quad){
        ctx.moveTo(workArray[0],workArray[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[2],workArray[3]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[4],workArray[5]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[6],workArray[7]);
        ctx.closePath();
    }else if(b.type === types.split1){
        ctx.moveTo(workArray[0],workArray[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[2],workArray[3]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[4],workArray[5]);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.moveTo(workArray[0],workArray[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[4],workArray[5]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[6],workArray[7]);
        ctx.closePath();
    }else if(b.type === types.split2){
        ctx.moveTo(workArray[0],workArray[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[2],workArray[3]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[6],workArray[7]);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.moveTo(workArray[2],workArray[3]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[4],workArray[5]);
        ctx.lineTo(workArray[6],workArray[7]);
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    if(edge){
        projection.toScreen(b.x + 1, b.y,     b.z, workArray, 8);
        projection.toScreen(b.x + 1, b.y + 1, b.z, workArray, 10);
        projection.toScreen(b.x,     b.y + 1, b.z, workArray, 12);
        if(edge === 1){ // right edge
            ctx.moveTo(workArray[2],workArray[3]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[8],workArray[9]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[10],workArray[11]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[4],workArray[5]);
        }
        if(edge === 2){ // right edge
            ctx.moveTo(workArray[4],workArray[5]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[10],workArray[11]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[12],workArray[13]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[6],workArray[7]);
        }
        if(edge === 3){ // right edge
            ctx.moveTo(workArray[2],workArray[3]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[8],workArray[9]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[10],workArray[11]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[12],workArray[13]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[6],workArray[7]);
            ctx.moveTo(workArray[10],workArray[11]);
            ctx.lineTo(workArray[4],workArray[5]);
        }
        
        
        
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}

function createMap(){
    var base = "0".charCodeAt(0);
    for(var y = 0; y < mapSize.depth; y ++){
        for(var x = 0; x < mapSize.width; x ++){
            var index = y * (mapSize.width + 1) + x;
            var b;
            var p1= map.charCodeAt(index)-base;
            var p2= map.charCodeAt(index+1)-base;
            var p3= map.charCodeAt(index+1+mapSize.width + 1)-base;
            var p4= map.charCodeAt(index+mapSize.width + 1)-base;
            var type;
            if((p1 === p2 && p3 === p4) || (p1 === p4 && p2 === p3)){
                type = types.quad;
            }else if(p1 === p3){
                type = types.split1;
            }else if(p4 === p2){
                type = types.split2;
            }else{
               // throw new RangeError("Map has badly formed block")
               type = types.split2;
            }
            blocks.push(
                b = createBlock(
                    x,y,0,p1,p2,p3,p4,type
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
function drawMap(){
   for(var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i ++){
       var edge = 0;
       if(i % mapSize.width === mapSize.width- 1){
           edge = 1;
       }
       if(Math.floor(i / mapSize.width) === mapSize.width- 1){
           edge |= 2;
       }
       drawBlock(blocks[i],"black",1,edge);
   }
}
function drawBallShadow(ball){
    var i;
    var x,y,ix,iy;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    var first = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i += 1/8){
        var ang = i * Math.PI * 2;
        x = ball.x + (ball.rad / projection.width ) * Math.cos(ang) * 0.7;
        y = ball.y + (ball.rad / projection.depth ) * Math.sin(ang) * 0.7;
        if(x < mapSize.width && x >= 0 && y < mapSize.depth && y > 0){
            ix = Math.floor(x + mapSize.width) % mapSize.width;
            iy = Math.floor(y + mapSize.depth) % mapSize.depth;
            var block = blocks[ix + iy * mapSize.width];
            var z = getHeight(block,x,y);
            projection.toScreen(x,y,z, pointArray);
            if(first === 0){
                first = 1;
                ctx.moveTo(pointArray[0],pointArray[1]);
            }else{
                ctx.lineTo(pointArray[0],pointArray[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    
}

function drawBall(ball){
    projection.toScreen(ball.x, ball.y, ball.z, pointArray);
    ctx.fillStyle = ball.col;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pointArray[0],pointArray[1],ball.rad,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pointArray[0]-ball.rad/2,pointArray[1]-ball.rad/2,ball.rad/4,0,Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}
function updateBall(ball){
    // reset ball if out of bounds;
    if(ball.x > mapSize.width || ball.y > mapSize.depth || ball.x < 0 || ball.y < 0){
        ball.x += ball.dx;
        ball.y += ball.dy;
        ball.z += ball.dz;
        ball.dz -= 0.1;
        if(ball.z < -10){
        
            ball.x = Math.random() * 3;
            ball.y = Math.random() * 3;
            ball.dz  = 0;
            // give random speed
            ball.dx = Math.random() * 0.01;
            ball.dy = Math.random() * 0.01;
        }else{
            ball.dist = Math.hypot(ball.x - 20,ball.y - 20, ball.z - 20);        
            return;
        }
        
    }
    // get the block under the ball
    var block = blocks[Math.floor(ball.x) + Math.floor(ball.y) * mapSize.width];
    const lastZ = ball.z;
    // get the height of the black at the balls position
    ball.z = getHeight(block,ball.x,ball.y);
    // use the face normal to add velocity in the direction of the normal
    ball.dx += block.pNorm.x * 0.01;
    ball.dy += block.pNorm.y * 0.01;
    // move the ball up by the amount of its radius
    ball.z += ball.rad / projection.height;
    ball.dz =lastZ - ball.z;
    // draw the shadow and ball
    ball.x += ball.dx;
    ball.y += ball.dy;
    // get distance from camera;
    ball.dist = Math.hypot(ball.x - 20,ball.y - 20, ball.z - 20);
}
function renderBall(ball){
    drawBallShadow(ball);
    drawBall(ball);
}
function copyCanvas(canvas){
    var can = document.createElement("canvas");
    can.width = canvas.width;
    can.height = canvas.height;
    can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    can.ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
    return can;    
}
var map = `
    9988888789999
    9887787678999
    9877676567899
    9876765678789
    9876655567789
    8766555456789
    7655554456678
    6654443456789
    6543334566678
    5432345677889
    4321234567789
    4321234567899
    5412345678999
`.replace(/\n| |\t/g,"");
var mapSize = {width : 12, depth : 12}; // one less than map width and depth
var blocks = [];
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
createMap();
drawMap();
var background = copyCanvas(canvas);
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var globalTime;  // global to this 
var balls = [{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "red",
        rad : 10,
    },{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "Green",
        rad : 10,
    },{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "Blue",
        rad : 10,
    },{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "yellow",
        rad : 10,
    },{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "cyan",
        rad : 10,
    },{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "black",
        rad : 10,
    },{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "white",
        rad : 10,
    },{
        x : -10,
        y : 0,
        z : 100,
        dx : 0,
        dy : 0,
        dz : 0,
        col : "orange",
        rad : 10,
    }
];

// main update function
function update(timer){
    globalTime = timer;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
    // get the block under the ball
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i ++){
        updateBall(balls[i]);
    }
    balls.sort((a,b)=>b.dist - a.dist);
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i ++){
        renderBall(balls[i]);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Comment: wow :O my mind is blown! if i call my self a programer then you must be god of programing :D Curntly I'm reading your code and trying to understand if i find some questions I'll definitely ask :) Thanks for showing me your approach on doing this and for your time spend creating working demo

Answer (score 1):

To handle collision detection of a point x with a block (which is like a cube but with slanted walls allowed), subtract the point x from the 3 points a,b,c that define the block, and then calculate the vector product of point vector x with the block point vector a',b',c' to give you 3 numbers A,B,C. If these numbers are between zero and the length of the vectors a,b,c squared respectively, the vector x is within the block. Or put another way that each A/(length a' squared), B/(length b' squared), C/(length c' squared) is less or equal 1 and greater than zero.

Likewise do for a tetrahedron, but with the additional condition that A/(length a' squared)+B/(length b' squared)+C/(length c' squared) is less or equal 1.

I hope theres no mistake in this, it is how I would approach the problem. This also doesn't handle the collision of two tetrahedrons edge-on-edge. So there is room for improvement over  what I said here. Especially, a collision check for edges with cubes or tetrahedrons would be nice.

For other shapes, divide these shapes up into cubes and tetrahedrons.

Comment: It's all fine but i have to do colision detection with other shapes too took at this [screen from original game](http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/4560/501894-spindizzy_16.gif)

Answer (score 1):

## General

I think for this game it would be enough to calculate the surface of the playground/base. Then for each point on the surface you can calculate the derivatives in all directions. Since they are all planes, this can simply be represented as a matrix of constants.

The player is always on `f( x, y ) = height` and changes `∇f( int(x), int(z) ) + v` with `v` being the force's vector inputed by the player.

The borders where the change is ∞ (solid walls) have to be handled separately by eg. calculating 'jumps' in f( x, y ).

---

**UPDATE 1**

## Approach

So Basically what you could do is create the following functions:

- `function height(x,y)` -> returning an integer

  - giving the height of the base at position (x,y)
- `function slope(x,y)` -> returning a tuple of two integers (including infinity)

  - giving the slope of the base at position (x,y) in x direction and in y direction

The 'player' starts at position `(x_0, y_0)` and has therefore height `z_0 = height(x_0, y_0)`.

The next position is then going to be
`(x_1, y_1) = (x_0, y_0) + s_g * slope(x_0, y_0) + s_u * v`, with height `z_1 = height(x_1, y_1)`.
`v`: vector representing the direction of movement the user wants to apply onto the 'player'.
`s_g`: speed/~gravity, 
`s_u`: speed the user controls the player with.

To handle gravity properly, the direction of the `slope` function would have to be reversed for positive directions.

To avoid the player going up 90deg. slopes:
Simply set `+infinity` values of the slope function to 0.

Comment: the biggest problem for me are [slopes](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ae/Spindizzy-Gameplay.png) could you describe how to change position while coliding with then? Or i didn't understand something